# Missing www in my url (on cellphone) causing "This connection is not private" ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, web-config, redirect, no-www

I've just published my website, and I realized missing www in my (BUT ONLY ON CELLPHONE) url causing this issue:

[image]

It is interesting fact that if I type url without www on my computer or laptop website is working fine, but if I type url without www on my cellphone, that is message that I'm getting (screenshot above).

So

> "https://example.com" // causing issue (because there is no www)
>
> "https://www.example.com" // works fine on my cellphone

I must say that I've tried editing `web.config` file, and I added this rule which should redirect all non www to www url, so my `web.config` looks like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>

        <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
        </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule> 

        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But I do not know what it's about, cuz it's causing issue only on cellphones looks like..

So any kind of help would be great!
Thanks

Comment: Anyone know what caused this? :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `https://`, all your urls must be with `https://`. If you will use `http://` this will cause errors. Additionaly, you have to setup certificate for both `https://www.sample.com` and `https://sample.com`

And check your `web.config` you use `http` insted of `https`

Comment: I thought I can redirect all non www to www, and it's fact that it's working on laptop/pc and not on cellphone..

Comment: Check your config, you have wrong url for redirect, use `https`.

Comment: another rule will redirect anyway all http to https, so that shouldn't be an issue..